# Google OAuth 2 API - PHP SDK - Undefined array key "expires_in"

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm using the latest version of the Google API Client PHP SDK (v2.11) to request an OAuth2 access token.

While retrieving an access token, I can see that the `expires_in` value is missing from the response, which leads to a PHP error when calling `isAccessTokenExpired()` later on:

**Step 1 - Retrieve an access and refresh token**

```
...
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
$_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();
var_dump($client->getAccessToken());
...
```

**Result**

```
array(1) { ["access_token"]=> string(163) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }
```

It seems that both the `expires_in` and `created` columns are missing from this answer.

**Step 2 - Let's check if the Access token has expired and needs to be refreshed**

```
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired())
{
    $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
```

**Result**

> Warning: Undefined array key "expires_in" in
> /var/www/admin/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php on line 554

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use. The library should be handling this for you.

[Oauth2Callback.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/oauth2callback.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Oauth2Authentication.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = buildClient();
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client = buildClient();
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // Exchange the authencation code for a refresh token and access token.
    // Add access token and refresh token to seession.
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();    
    //Redirect back to main script
    $redirect_uri = str_replace("oauth2callback.php",$_SESSION['mainScript'],$client->getRedirectUri());    
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

?>
```

[Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    $client = getOauth2Client();

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
return $client;
}

/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed.
 * Example:  array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function buildClient(){
    
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
    $client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());  
    return $client;
}

/**
 * Builds the redirect uri.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app#choosingredirecturi
 * Hostname and current server path are needed to redirect to oauth2callback.php
 * @return A redirect uri.
 */
function getRedirectUri(){

    //Building Redirect URI
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];                    //returns the current URL
    if(strrpos($url, '?') > 0)
        $url = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '?') );  // Removing any parameters.
    $folder = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/') );   // Removeing current file.
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $folder. '/oauth2callback.php';
}


/**
 * Authenticating to Google using Oauth2
 * Documentation:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Returns a Google client with refresh token and access tokens set. 
 *  If not authencated then we will redirect to request authencation.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {
        
        $client = buildClient();
        
        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }
        
        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            
            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 
            
            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My API response was missing `expires_in` due to retrieving the tokens twice in my redirect.php script (called after the user has been authenticated).

As described [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/213), the OAuth refresh token as well as `expires_in` value are provided to you only during the first authorization. Adding a `consent` prompt also helped to address this issue.

If you are doing some testing and need to reset the authorization you gave, you can do it here: https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

**Here's the full script, which is now working:**

```
<?php

include(__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri(BASE_URL.'/redirect.php');
$client->addScope('email');
$client->addScope('profile');
$client->setPrompt('consent');

if (isset($_GET['code']) && !empty($_GET['code']))
{
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    if ($client->getAccessToken())
    {
        $google_oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
        $google_account_info = $google_oauth->userinfo->get();

        if (!isset($google_account_info->hd) || $google_account_info->hd != 'mydomain.com')
            die('This domain name has not been authorized.');
        else
        {
            $redirect_uri = BASE_URL.(isset($_GET['state']) ? $_GET['state'] : '/');
            $_SESSION['picture'] = $google_account_info->picture;
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
            $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();
            $_SESSION['token_expiration'] = time() + 3600;

            header('Location: '.filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

It includes a domain check (i.e. replace mydomain.com by your own domain) as well as a referrer callback (i.e. populate `state` on your login page with the referrer first).